# Very strange url in IE with page 404 error

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer, coldfusion

I have an index.cfm file and I also have a header and footer.cfm files. In addition, I used cfinclude to include the templates. The structure is a bit complicated but it's not something that I can change at this point.

I'm using ColdFusion2016 and plain HTML with a few jquery codes for simple things like pop up message or date picker. This application works GREAT in FireFox and Chrome but NOT in IE. The IE version that I have in my machine is version 11.0.9600 and I don't have any other version to test.

I think the problem doesn't seem to be related to either coldfusion or anything else because it has something to do with the  in navigation menu. When I click any item from that menu I get IE's error:

The webpage cannot be found and at the bottom I can see the following error message:
This error (HTTP 404 Not Found) means that Internet Explorer was able to connect to the website, but the page you wanted was not found. It’s possible that the webpage is temporarily unavailable. Alternatively, the website might have changed or removed the webpage.
For more information about HTTP errors, see Help.

In the url I got en extra characters which I don't find when I use FireFox and Chrome.
So here is the extra characters that causing this issue and I don't know how they get there and not sure where can I start to fix this issue:

The header codes look like this (I just copied three items from the menu):

```
<ul id="minitabs">
  <li><a id="#url.home#" href="index.cfm?p=home&home=current" 
      target="iframe_main">HOME</a> <font color="a4a4a4">|</font></li>
  <li><a id="#url.form#" href="index.cfm?p=form&form=current" 
      target="iframe_main">FORMS</a> <font color="a4a4a4">|</font></li>
  <li><a id="#url.research#" href="index.cfm?p=research&research=current" 
      target="iframe_main">RESEARCH</a> <font color="a4a4a4">|</font></li>
</ul>
```

So if I click on FORMS in FireFox and Chrome, everything works and this is what I see in my browser's URL:

https://testserver1.com/index.cfm?p=form&form=current

But if I open the same item or any item from that menu in IE, this is what I see:

https://testserver2.com/index.cfm;jsessionid=A93A2E2D5C0006326955F9A8EC8C45D8.cfusion?p=form&form=current

There is an extra script in there starts with ;jsessionid.. that broke the link

One strange things is that when I corrected the url in IE not only the page shows up but also I can never regenerate IE error again in my machine. But in a different machine I still get the error with IE and not with firefox or chrome

Here are how the structure of my index.cfm:

```
 <cfinclude template="header.cfm">
    <CFIF NOT IsDefined("url.p")>
      <cfinclude template="home.cfm">
    <CFELSE>
      <CFSWITCH expression="#p#">
         <CFCASE value="form"><cfinclude template="formindex.cfm"></CFCASE>
         ...etc
      </CFSWITCH>
    </CFIF>
<cfinclude template="footer.cfm">
```

Comment: Try deleting all of IE's browser cache AND cookies. Then try again.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this page: http://www.talkingtree.com/blog/index.cfm/2004/7/23/JSessionID404

This sounds like a session fixation issue. You are getting the 404 because your webserver thinks the file being requested is ";jsessionblahblah.cfusion".